# Regarding line item display at PayPal site

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are currently looking at displaying the order level line items – Order Total, Item Total, Total Shipping, Total Tax (which are still passed as part of PaymentDetails).

For the above requirement we are passing all the required details in the SetExpressCheckoutReq.

Please let me know how can we achieve it.

As part of SetExpressCheckoutReq we are passing:

```
    <ebl:PaymentDetails>
              <ebl:OrderTotal currencyID="USD">359.94</ebl:OrderTotal>
             <ebl:ItemTotal currencyID="USD">309.99</ebl:ItemTotal>
              <ebl:ShippingTotal currencyID="USD">49.95</ebl:ShippingTotal>
              <ebl:TaxTotal currencyID="USD">0.0</ebl:TaxTotal>
              <ebl:OrderDescription>Order Total: 359.94</ebl:OrderDescription>
              <ebl:PaymentAction>Order</ebl:PaymentAction>
      </ebl:PaymentDetails>
```

2014-08-05T18:04:20Z
         Success
         aab008f9d690d
         98.0
         12194268
         EC-4KY406765L816782W

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the  node, one for each item.  Inside that are child elements for the item details like name, price, qty, etc. which you'll find in the PaymentDetailsItem Type Fields section of the [SetExpressCheckout API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_SOAP/).

Also, keep in mind that you'll need to include the same details in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment request in order for the line item details to show up in the final transaction details at PayPal.